# Make a one word command for my script to use in ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, command

I have a script `/home/user/tde.sh` I want to make a one work command that will run this script when I type it into a terminal.
So if I write "tetras" in a terminal window it will run my `/home/user/tde.sh`. How can I achieve this in ubuntu?

P.S. This is to help me achieve a desktop environment goal as I only need the desktop everynow and then I just want a quick command to run this script which will in turn start my desktop environment I am developing.

Answer (score 2):

`# alias tetras=/home/user/tde.sh`

If you wish, put that in your .bashrc file.

http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?alias+1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create a function for it:

```
function tetras {
     bash /home/user/tde.sh "$@"
}
```

And place it in `~/.bashrc`.